# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime ParseExact Error

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert a datarow item to a datetime then i only want to show the Hours and Mins.

When i run this i get the following error
"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
Code

```
 DateTime PushinValue = DateTime.ParseExact(dataRow[0].ToString(), "HH:mm", null);
```

dataRow[0] is a `DateTime`

What is causing the Error does anyone know any ways to get around this error.

I have tried to do this with .Parse Ect.

Any help at all appricated.

Comment: Could you tell us what is the result of `dataRow[0].ToString()`?

Comment: The outcome for dataRow[0].ToString is "28/03/2013 11:03:00"

Comment: What is the use of creating a DateTime by parsing another DateTime? If you only want hours:mins why don't you just use them from `dataRow[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to just get the time element in the HH:mm format, then;

```
DateTime PushinValue = DateTime.Parse(dataRow[0].ToString());
    String myTime = PushinValue.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String _mydatestring = DateTime.ParseExact(dataRow[0].ToString,"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss").ToString("HH:mm")
```

Comment: I get a error "Error 6 No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: Ok, so your dataRow[0] is a string representing a date & time. I've updated the code sample above.

Comment: try changing the . for a / like this e.g From "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" to "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse "28.03.2013 13:11:28" to "hh:mm" :-) Why do you parse DateTime into DateTime then format it?

Why not simply this:

```
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        Debug.WriteLine(dt.ToString("hh:mm"));
```

Comment: Does DateTime.Now not only return the current time. I need to convert the value that is in dataRow[0] to just "hh:mm"